# installing XV-11 driver git error

Tags: ros, rosinstall, xv-11-laser-driver, git

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm following the directions from here,
http://www.ros.org/wiki/xv_11_laser_driver/Tutorials/Running%20the%20XV-11%20Node
I installed Cturtle and then when I try to install the driver I get this.

linux$ rosinstall ~/cwru-ros-pkg /opt/ros/cturtle 'http://www.ros.org/wiki/xv_11_laser_driver/Tutorials/Running%20the%20XV-11%20Node?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=cwru-ros-pkg.rosinstall'
rosinstall operating on /home/ringo/cwru-ros-pkg from specifications in rosinstall files  /opt/ros/cturtle, http://www.ros.org/wiki/xv_11_laser_driver/Tutorials/Running%20the%20XV-11%20Node?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=cwru-ros-pkg.rosinstall
processing config_uri /opt/ros/cturtle
ERROR: woah, unknown installation method git not installed, cannot create a git vcs client

So do I need to install GIT or is there another way?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10458/installing-xv-11-driver-git-error/) by [ringo42](https://answers.ros.org/users/651/ringo42/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2011-07-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How about trying to install git:

```
sudo apt-get install git-core
```

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1